# UINavigationBar calling drawRect: if subclassed but not when using categories in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using iOS 5 SDK in a project which has iOS 4.0 as target and I've noticed that if I subclass the UINavigationBar class to override the `drawRect:` method it gets called, but this doesn't happen when creating a category from UINavigationBar class.

Does anybody knows why is this happening? I should have misunderstood categories or something, because this behavior has no sense to me.

Edit: I'm running the application on iOS 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[iOS 5.0 SDK Release Notes, UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010949-CH1-SW29):

> In iOS 5, the `UINavigationBar`, `UIToolbar`, and `UITabBar` implementations have changed so that the `drawRect:` method is not called unless it is implemented in a subclass. Apps that have re-implemented `drawRect:` in a category on any of these classes will find that the `drawRect:` method isn't called. UIKit does link-checking to keep the method from being called in apps linked before iOS 5 but does not support this design on iOS 5 or later. Apps can either:
>
> - Use the customization API for bars in iOS 5 and later, which is the preferred way.
> - Subclass `UINavigationBar` (or the other bar classes) and override `drawRect:` in the subclass.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't read that before asking. Thank you, things have much more sense now.

Comment: You just saved me a full night of being angry at iOS/Xcode. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between categories and subclasses.  A subclass involves inheritance, which means you can override method implementations such as `drawRect:`.  A category is used to add methods to an existing class, also known as extensions.

For example, to add a method to NSString, you can create a category like so:

```
@interface NSString (MyStringAdditions)
- (void)doSomething;
@end
```

The alternative is to subclass like so:

```
@interface MyStringClass : NSString
- (void)doSomething;
@end
```

The difference lies in usability.  If you subclass, you have to have instances of that subclass to call the methods.  If you use a category, your new method will work on all objects of that existing class.

Comment: Could be possible that if I try to override the drawRect: method in a category it's not overriden but if I subclass it is?

Comment: You shouldn't add existing methods to categories.  It causes a conflict and usually your code doesn't get called.  In order to write your own drawRect, the best way is to subclass, but don't forget to call `[super drawRect:]`

Comment: It is curious because the category thing worked for iOS 4. I know that drawRect: doesn't get called in iOS 5, but I'm starting to think that this is not completely true.

Comment: Not sure how it would have worked, or even compiled for that matter.